# POSTing files within a folder

Tags: activex

I have this unusual requirement from a client, and I am not quite sure how to proceed.

My client needs to select a folder from his computer in IE and POST the files within that folder to the server. I was thinking of an ActiveX control. Could you point me to the right way? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a tricky question; You can certainly upload files using WinHttp or WinInet (forget which works better for it) but you could run into issues with proxy settings.

If I were you I'd write a plugin using [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org), which would then work on all major browsers instead of just IE (works both as an ActiveX control and as a NPAPI plugin). There is a library for FireBreath that though poorly documented allows you to upload files via HTTP using libcurl and openssl, or you could figure out how to do it with WinInet/WinHTTP (do some google searches, several possible leads come up).